# XSLT to transform HTML list into XML

Tags: xml, xslt, xhtml

**Issue:**
*Solved, I was able to produce a script that will go through my XHTML list and produce XML output.*

The question was:
What should the XSLT look like, when I have an ordered list?

Thanks @Sbof

I need to produce the following XML:

```
<ParagraphStyleRange AppliedParagraphStyle="ParagraphStyle/ul">
  <CharacterStyleRange AppliedCharacterStyle="CharacterStyle/Character Style 1">
    <Content>abc</Content>
    <Br/>
    <Content>xyz</Content>
    <Br/>
    <Content>abc</Content>
    <Br/>
    <Content>xyzabc</Content>
    <Br/>
  </CharacterStyleRange>
</ParagraphStyleRange>
<ParagraphStyleRange AppliedParagraphStyle="ParagraphStyle/ol level 1">
  <CharacterStyleRange AppliedCharacterStyle="CharacterStyle/Character Style 1">
    <Content>xyz</Content>
    <Br/>
  </CharacterStyleRange>
</ParagraphStyleRange>
<ParagraphStyleRange AppliedParagraphStyle="ParagraphStyle/ol level 2">
  <CharacterStyleRange AppliedCharacterStyle="CharacterStyle/Character Style 1">
    <Content>abc</Content>
    <Br/>
  </CharacterStyleRange>
</ParagraphStyleRange>
```

I have XHTML (The content is different, but does same thing) that looks like this:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head>
    <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" />
    <title></title>
</head>
<body>
<ol>
    <li>abc</li>
    <li>xyz</li>
    <li>abc</li>
    <li>xyzabc</li>
    <li>xyz<ol>
        <li>abc</li>
        </ol>
    </li>
    <li>xyzxyz</li>
    <li>abc</li>
    <ol>
        <li>xyz</li>
    </ol>
    <li>next level</li>
</ol>
</body>
</html>
```

This is a snippet of XSLT to transverse the XHTML:

```
  <xsl:template match="xhtml:ol/xhtml:li[not(*)]">
    <xsl:call-template name="para-style-range">
      <xsl:with-param name="style-name">article%3aol Level 1</xsl:with-param>
    </xsl:call-template>
    <xsl:if test ="xhtml:ol/xhtml:li[*]|
                   xhtml:ul/xhtml:li[*]">
      <xsl:apply-templates select="xhtml:ol/xhtml:li[*]|
                                   xhtml:ul/xhtml:li[*]" />
    </xsl:if>
  </xsl:template>
```

This is the result I get using my script:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" standalone="yes"?>
<idPkg:Story xmlns:idPkg="http://ns.adobe.com/AdobeInDesign/idml/1.0/packaging" DOMVersion="7.5">
    <Story Self="ucb" AppliedTOCStyle="n" TrackChanges="false" StoryTitle="$ID/" AppliedNamedGrid="n">
        <StoryPreference OpticalMarginAlignment="false" OpticalMarginSize="12" FrameType="TextFrameType" StoryOrientation="Horizontal" StoryDirection="LeftToRightDirection"/>
        <InCopyExportOption IncludeGraphicProxies="true" IncludeAllResources="false"/>
        <ParagraphStyleRange AppliedParagraphStyle="ParagraphStyle/ul">
            <CharacterStyleRange AppliedCharacterStyle="CharacterStyle/Character Style 1">
                <Content>abc</Content>
                <Br/>
                <Content>xyz</Content>
                <Br/>
                <Content>abc</Content>
                <Br/>
                <Content>xyzabc</Content>
                <Br/>
            </CharacterStyleRange>
        </ParagraphStyleRange>
        <ParagraphStyleRange AppliedParagraphStyle="ParagraphStyle/ol level 1">
            <CharacterStyleRange AppliedCharacterStyle="CharacterStyle/Character Style 1">
                <Content>xyz</Content>
                <Br/>
            </CharacterStyleRange>
        </ParagraphStyleRange>
        <ParagraphStyleRange AppliedParagraphStyle="ParagraphStyle/ol level 2">
            <CharacterStyleRange AppliedCharacterStyle="CharacterStyle/Character Style 1">
                <Content>abc</Content>
                <Br/>
            </CharacterStyleRange>
        </ParagraphStyleRange>
        <ParagraphStyleRange AppliedParagraphStyle="ParagraphStyle/ol level 1">
            <CharacterStyleRange AppliedCharacterStyle="CharacterStyle/Character Style 1">
                <Content>xyzxyz</Content>
                <Br/>
                <Content>abc</Content>
                <Br/>
            </CharacterStyleRange>
        </ParagraphStyleRange>
        <ParagraphStyleRange AppliedParagraphStyle="ParagraphStyle/ol level 3">
            <CharacterStyleRange AppliedCharacterStyle="CharacterStyle/Character Style 1">
                <Content>xyz</Content>
                <Br/>
            </CharacterStyleRange>
        </ParagraphStyleRange>
        <ParagraphStyleRange AppliedParagraphStyle="ParagraphStyle/ol level 1">
            <CharacterStyleRange AppliedCharacterStyle="CharacterStyle/Character Style 1">
                <Content>next level</Content>
                <Br/>
            </CharacterStyleRange>
        </ParagraphStyleRange>
    </Story>
</idPkg:Story>
```

XSLT snipped to get the attribute value of paragraph:

```
<xsl:template name="para-style-range">
    <!-- The name of the paragraph style in InDesign -->
    <xsl:param name="style-name"/>
    <xsl:param name ="isTable" />
    <!-- A string of text that will precede the paragraph's actual content (ex: 'by ')-->
    <xsl:param name="prefix-content" select="''"/>
    <ParagraphStyleRange>
      <xsl:attribute name="AppliedParagraphStyle">
        <xsl:value-of select="concat('ParagraphStyle/', $style-name)"/>
      </xsl:attribute>
      <xsl:if test="$prefix-content != ''">
        <CharacterStyleRange>
          <Content><xsl:value-of select="$prefix-content"/></Content>
        </CharacterStyleRange>
      </xsl:if>
      <xsl:apply-templates select="text()|*" mode="character-style-range"/>
      <xsl:choose>
        <xsl:when test ="$isTable = 'true'">
          <!--Dont do any thing here-->
        </xsl:when>
        <xsl:otherwise>
          <Br/>
        </xsl:otherwise>
      </xsl:choose>

    </ParagraphStyleRange>
  </xsl:template>
```

Let me know if I can provide more script to help those who are still confused about the code or need help figuring it out.

Comment: Shouldn't it look like your snippet?

Comment: Yes your right on that, I'm pretty close. Do you know any good idea's or hints on where to go from here? This code goes to deep and gets everything, I want to break it down by levels. I'm trans-versing XHTML to produce XML, but the XML produced creates another result. I'll share that as well.

Comment: It would really help if you explain *in the question* exactly what is wrong with that you have.

Comment: Sorry, I'll try again. I need to produce a script that will go through a list and create a attribute "AppliedParagraphStyle" with a value of the level that it's currently at. While in the recursion, we start off at level1, then we have a sub list, so we are now in level 2, etc. I hope this helps.

Comment: However, my script for some reason goes to deep and outputs all of the levels as level 1.

Comment: Just updated my post with the result of my script...

Comment: I don't see where in your script you're calculating the attribute value but why don't you just count the parent ol's to determine the level. Something like `count(parent::ol)`?

Comment: Can you add an example of what the exact output should be using your "xhtml input snippet"? It's hard to tell if the `ParagraphStyleRange` elements are supposed to be nested.

Comment: The source XML document doesn't contain at all strings like the ones in the provided wanted output. Voted to Close, and -1.

Comment: I'll provide all of the output for the XML output, but please don't close my post I need some assistance.

Comment: @user463324 I'll add the code snipped for how I retrieve the attribute value.

Comment: @DimitreNovatchev and DevNull - I tryied my best to tailor the HTML to you so it matches the output, does this work for you?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The following XSL works on your example:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<xsl:stylesheet xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform" version="1.0"
    xmlns:html="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml"
    exclude-result-prefixes="html">
    <xsl:template match="text()"/>
    <xsl:template match="/">
        <rootElement>
            <xsl:apply-templates/>
        </rootElement>
    </xsl:template>
    <xsl:template match="//html:ol">
        <ParagraphStyleRange>
            <xsl:attribute name="AppliedParagraphStyle">
                <xsl:text>ParagraphStyle/ol level </xsl:text>
                <xsl:value-of select="count(ancestor::html:ol)"/>
            </xsl:attribute>
            <xsl:apply-templates select="child::html:li"/>
        </ParagraphStyleRange>
        <xsl:apply-templates select="descendant::html:ol"/>
    </xsl:template>

    <xsl:template match="//html:li">
        <CharacterStyleRange>
            <xsl:attribute name="AppliedCharacterStyle">
                <xsl:text>CharacterStyle/Character Style </xsl:text>
                <xsl:value-of select="count(ancestor::html:li)"/>
            </xsl:attribute>
        <Content>
            <xsl:value-of select="normalize-space(text())"/>
        </Content>
        <br/>
        </CharacterStyleRange>
    </xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

The exact input I used was

```
<!DOCTYPE html SYSTEM "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
    <head>
        <title></title>
    </head>
    <body>
        <ol>
            <li>level1a</li>
            <li>level1b
                <ol>
                    <li>level2a</li>
                    <li>level2b</li>
                    <li>level2c
                        <ol>
                            <li>level3a</li>
                        </ol>
                    </li>
                </ol>
            </li>
        </ol>
    </body>
</html>
```

You might need to adapt this to your exact need.